# How to safely turn off EAP controller and my TP-LINK EAP110 Access Point so that it does not disconnect the access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a [TP-LINK EAP110 Access Point](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/EAP110.html). It is connected to my ADSL modem and NETGEAR WiFi router. Everyday we need to turn the PC, router and access point off. And whenever we start them again in the morning, the EAP Controller shows that access point is disconnected. Then we have to make the EAP Controller forget it and then we adopt it again to the EAP Controller. So what can I do so that everytime I turn on everything and start the EAP controller it should adopt the Access Point automatically?

Comment: Why are you turning everything off?

Comment: @DavidPostill to save electricity and we turn off AC and fans at night so also to avoid damage because of heat.